# scrapy returns different status code from python-requests, for GET request with with same headers and method

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

For a while, I've been using the cloudscraper package to scrape data from websites with CloudFlare protection. This method recently stopped working. While investigating the issue, it seems like scrapy fails (gets a 503 and captcha page) while the same request, with the same headers using 'requests.get' succeeds'.

To Replicate:

```
>>> fetch('https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94')
2020-11-23 16:13:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (503) <GET https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94> (referer: None)
```

So just trying to fetch the page returns a CloudFlare protection page. Also If I use python requests, the result is the same (503 response):

```
>>> import requests
>>> rq_response = requests.get('https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94')
2020-11-23 16:21:47 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): targetlaos.com:443
2020-11-23 16:21:47 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://targetlaos.com:443 "GET /category/news/%E0%BA%82%E0%BB%88%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%A7-%E0%BA%9E%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%8D%E0%BB%83%E0%BA%99%E0%BA%9B%E0%BA%B0%E0%BB%80%E0%BA%97%E0%BA%94 HTTP/1.1" 503 None
```

Therefore I use cloudscraper to get the proper headers/cookies:

```
>>> import cloudscraper
>>> cs = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
>>> cs_response = cs.get('https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94')
2020-11-23 16:19:16 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): targetlaos.com:443
2020-11-23 16:19:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://targetlaos.com:443 "GET /category/news/%E0%BA%82%E0%BB%88%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%A7-%E0%BA%9E%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%8D%E0%BB%83%E0%BA%99%E0%BA%9B%E0%BA%B0%E0%BB%80%E0%BA%97%E0%BA%94 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
# Note: I do the below for the second time, so I can capture the request-headers for testing. I'm aware I can do this more efficiently
>>> cs_response = cs.get('https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94')
2020-11-23 16:25:19 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://targetlaos.com:443 "GET /category/news/%E0%BA%82%E0%BB%88%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%A7-%E0%BA%9E%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%8D%E0%BB%83%E0%BA%99%E0%BA%9B%E0%BA%B0%E0%BB%80%E0%BA%97%E0%BA%94 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
>>> cs_response.request.headers
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Cookie': '__cf_bm=03ac0515966d1267f42bd7d107562a0b9d5d3362-1606148357-1800-AYHPir56JSKk63KtQUR1vGzVipMSH3fHiDSDO/ireLEQ; __cfduid=dead0a14752f609eba026cd5f982dccec1606148356; wppas_pvbl=%5B%2252735%22%2C52736%5D; wppas_user_stats=%7B%221606089600%22%3A%7B%22impressions%22%3A%7B%22banners%22%3A%5B%2252735%22%2C52736%5D%7D%2C%22clicks%22%3A%7B%22banners%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D%7D'}
```

So if this request now works with these cookies, I should be able to use them in scrapy, to get data:

```
>>> fetch('https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94', headers=cs_response.request.headers)
2020-11-23 16:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (503) <GET https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94> (referer: None)
```

So it's not working in scrapy. To check if it didn't change the headers (I disabled all downloader middlewares for testing):

```
>>> response.request.headers
{b'User-Agent': [b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0'], b'Accept': [b'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'], b'Accept-Language': [b'en-US,en;q=0.5'], b'Accept-Encoding': [b'gzip, deflate'], b'Cookie': [b'__cf_bm=03ac0515966d1267f42bd7d107562a0b9d5d3362-1606148357-1800-AYHPir56JSKk63KtQUR1vGzVipMSH3fHiDSDO/ireLEQ; __cfduid=dead0a14752f609eba026cd5f982dccec1606148356; wppas_pvbl=%5B%2252735%22%2C52736%5D; wppas_user_stats=%7B%221606089600%22%3A%7B%22impressions%22%3A%7B%22banners%22%3A%5B%2252735%22%2C52736%5D%7D%2C%22clicks%22%3A%7B%22banners%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D%7D']}
```

If I try the same request with python requests:

```
>>> requests.get('https://targetlaos.com/category/news/%e0%ba%82%e0%bb%88%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%a7-%e0%ba%9e%e0%ba%b2%e0%ba%8d%e0%bb%83%e0%ba%99%e0%ba%9b%e0%ba%b0%e0%bb%80%e0%ba%97%e0%ba%94', headers=cs_response.request.headers)
2020-11-23 16:33:13 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): targetlaos.com:443
2020-11-23 16:33:14 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://targetlaos.com:443 "GET /category/news/%E0%BA%82%E0%BB%88%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%A7-%E0%BA%9E%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%8D%E0%BB%83%E0%BA%99%E0%BA%9B%E0%BA%B0%E0%BB%80%E0%BA%97%E0%BA%94 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
<Response [200]>
```

So the 'same' request (Or: The request that I'm expecting to be exactly the same) does work in python requests but not in scrapy. Does anyone have an idea why this is?

*Note: I've tested the above on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 and Python 3.7.9, because from my local IP I'm not getting the cloudflare page*

What I've tried:

- Disabling all downloader middlewares
- Newest versions of Scrapy (2.4.1)

Comment: You could point both requests to http://httpbin.org/anything and compare, to see how similar they actually are.

Some sites can fail to serve a response based on things beyond the request content, though. See a recent issue which basically brings up your question: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4951

Comment: Hi @Gallaecio, thanks for your suggestions! I've tried it, and the headers of both requests are the same when sending them to Httpbin (There is a "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" which is different, but I believe this is added on the side of httpbin). I also tried the suggestion from the linked issue to use 'DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD='TLSv1.2'', but that also didn't change things. Probably there's some difference in the lower level protocol that CloudFlare is picking up. If you have any more suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: You could try with https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright, just for the sake of trying something else.